# Android FileProvider delete file

Tags: android

Am working in a photo gallery app, due to the recent nougat update i couldn't delete file from gallery.
I found out that I have to use `Fileprovider` for file access, I tried below code but it says

```
04-25 12:52:03.031 3204-4133/com.zo.tns1 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
                                                       Process: com.zo.tns1, PID: 3204
                                                       java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
                                                           at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:325)
                                                           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
                                                           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
                                                           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                                                           at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
                                                           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                                                           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                                                           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
                                                        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.io.File android.support.v4.content.FileProvider$PathStrategy.getFileForUri(android.net.Uri)' on a null object reference
                                                           at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.delete(FileProvider.java:520)
                                                           at com.zo.tns1.tasks.DeleteMediaTask.doInBackground(DeleteMediaTask.java:117)
                                                           at com.zo.tns1.tasks.DeleteMediaTask.doInBackground(DeleteMediaTask.java:39)
                                                           at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:305)
                                                           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                           at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243) 
                                                           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
                                                           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
                                                           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

**Manifest**

```
<provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.zo.tns1.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/fileaccess_paths"/>
    </provider>
```

**fileaccess_paths.xml**

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<external-path name="all_files" path="." />
```

**Java Code**

```
File f = new File(mediaList.get(i).getMediaPath());    
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                FileProvider provider = new FileProvider();
                Uri deleteFileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context.getApplicationContext(), "com.zo.tns1.fileprovider", f);
                context.grantUriPermission(context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), deleteFileUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                provider.delete(deleteFileUri, null, null);
                //context.getContentResolver().delete(deleteFileUri, null, null);
            } else {
                boolean b = f.delete();
                Log.d(TAG, "File delete -> " + b);
            }
```

**FilePath**

```
/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20170421_112804_1.jpg
```

Comment: Which line causes the NPE?

Comment: I suggest that you read the documentation for [FileProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html).

Comment: provider.delete(deleteFileUri, null, null);this line returing null eventhough uri is not null

Comment: provider.delete() returns an int, which cannot be null. Please post the entire stacktrace.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, i updated crash report.

Comment: What is line 117 in DeleteMediaTask.java?

Comment: provider.delete(deleteFileUri, null, null);

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I want to delete a file, which is not happening in Nougat

Comment: You should use the Android Studio debugger or Log.d() to check if the URI is null. Most likely you cannot create a FileProvider by calling the constructor. Instead you need to use the ContentResolver.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Logged uri -> content://com.zo.tns1.fileprovider/all_files/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp%20Images/IMG-20170427-WA0008.jpg

Comment: Most likely the problem is what was already started in the answer below. You should use ContentResolver rather than create the FileProvider manually.

Comment: context.getContentResolver().delete(deleteFileUri, null, null); 
I have tested this in emulator api23,24,25 and MotoXPlay_api23, SamsungS7edge_api24, OnePlus3_api25. this works in all devices except OnePlus3, it returns 0;

Answer (score 10):

You can't just use the `FileProvider` constructor like that, you need to go via your context's content resolver. That will give you the provider you've specified in the manifest. Something like

```
context.getContentResolver().delete(deleteFileUri, null, null);
```

Comment: This will only delete data in contentprovider, but the file will still be there

Comment: @ArunShankar FileProvider extends ContentProvider, so this should work as long as you get the correct provider.

Comment: I agree with @Code-Apprentice on this. It's working fine for me.