# Why ContentResolver delete returns 0 in particular device

Tags: android, android-studio

Am developing a gallery app, in which user can delete the images, however **delete** functionality not working in OnePlus3.

Five days ago I asked a similar question before testing on multiple devices [Android FileProvider delete file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43536531/android-fileprovider-delete-file), Then only i found out the real scenerio.

The devices which i tested:

```
Emulator-Pixel XL API25 - Working
Emulator-Pixel XL API24 - Working
Emulator-Nexus 5X API25 - Working
Emulator-Nexus 5 API23 - Working
Device-MotoXPlay API23 - Working
Device-MotoXForce API24 - Working
Device-SamsungS7Edge API24 - Working
Device-OnePlusX API23 - Working
Device-OnePlus3 API25 - Not Working
```

**manifest**

```
<provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.zo.tns1.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/fileaccess_paths"/>
```

**paths**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <paths>
    <external-path
        name="external"
        path="." />
    <internal-path
        name="internal"
        path="." />
    </paths>
```

**Code**

```
Uri deleteFileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "com.zo.tns1.fileprovider", new File(filePath));
int fileDeleted = context.getContentResolver().delete(deleteFileUri, null, null);
Log.d(TAG, "File delete -> " + fileDeleted);
```

**URI output**

```
/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20170421_112804_1.jpg
```

`context.getContentResolver().delete()` returns **0** in OnePlus3, couldn't find the real reason. Is this anything because of oxygen OS ?

Any help is appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: What is f? Full path please.

Comment: deleteFileUri.toString() value please.

Comment: is this the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43536531/android-fileprovider-delete-file ?

Comment: @k3b, yes thats before i tested on different devices, actually the problem arises in oneplus3 only

Comment: @greenapps, i have updated uri value

Comment: ???? I see no f Why dont you just use f.delete(); ?

Comment: I tried file.delete() thats also returns false in onePlus3

Comment: So why all the fuss? Why didnt you tell before? I asked for two paths and you gave only one and you did not give the rigth one.

Comment: Can you create a file in that directory? Come to the point please.

Comment: @greenapps, I understand that i should've elaborated the cases here, but deleting from both content provider & file are these same only right?

Comment: @greenapps let me check & tell

Comment: @greenapps, ya am able to create files (.txt, .png)

Comment: Then you should be able to delete them too.

Comment: Ya, it should be, but I can't delete media, but google photos app & some other gallery apps are working properly